# How to compile code where field has exactly the same name as a type?

Tags: c++

I copy-paste some code from [here](https://github.com/majek/openonload/blob/master/src/tests/ef_vi/efsink.c) and can not compile. Problem with this part:

```
struct pkt_buf {
/* I/O address corresponding to the start of this pkt_buf struct */
ef_addr            ef_addr;
```

I have this error:

```
openonload-201509/src/include/etherfabric/ef_vi.h:119:33: error: changes meaning of ‘ef_addr’ from ‘typedef uint64_t ef_addr’ [-fpermissive]
typedef uint64_t                ef_addr;
```

As I understand I can not use the same name for a type and for a field.
But library I've linked is widely-used and it must compile.
May be something wrong with my compiler settings? How can I compile my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The source code is `efsink.c`, which is a C file.

This code is valid in C but not valid in C++ (I think).

You should use a C compiler to compile C files. C and C++ are different languages.

The major C++ compilers also come bundled with a C compiler, and usually they autodetect the language based on filename (but this can be overridden with switches).

You can have a project that contains some C files and some C++ files, but you must use a C compiler for the C files and use a C++ compiler for the C++ files.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Unfortunately I am not certain why this problem arises</strike> EDIT: This problem arises because many things are valid in C but not in C++ - for example, declaring an array with a dynamic length i.e. `int bob[x]` is valid in C but not in C++. Looking at the link, it is a C file and should be compiled with `gcc`.

> `openonload-201509/src/include/etherfabric/ef_vi.h:119:33: error: changes meaning of ‘ef_addr’ from ‘typedef uint64_t ef_addr’ [-fpermissive]`

<strike>This makes the solution quite obvious if you use g++ - add `-fpermissive` to your compiler flags.</strike> NO, don't do that! Use a C compiler, or rather, use `gcc`. The code is written in C and should be treated as such.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. `-fpermissive` should not be used unless you know what you're doing. It makes significant changes to the language, and the result means that valid C++ code can get rejected.

Comment: Yes, sorry, updated my answer when I realised that the code was written in C.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the (always cryptic!) standard:

> 3.3.7  [basic.scope.class]
>
> 2) A name N used in a class S shall refer to the same declaration in its context and when re-evaluated in the completed scope of S. No diagnostic is required for a violation of this rule.

In the above class, following the declaration of `ef_addr ef_addr;`, the name `ef_addr` now refers to a member and not a type (within the scope of class `pkt_buf`.

GCC has chosen to issue a diagnostic. clang in this situation does not. Both are correct.

If you're able to change the header then I would turn off this error by surrounding the class definition with a `#pragma` to turn off the warning locally.

If not, put the pragma around the inclusion of the header (i.e. as tightly scoped as possible)